# Reverse for '' with arguments '' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have urls:

```
url(r'^tournament/(?P<tournament_id>\d+)/tour/$', chess.views.first_tour, name = 'first_tour'),    
url(r'^tournament/(?P<tournament_id>\d+)/tour/match/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', chess.views.edit_match, name = 'edit_match'),
```

Views:

```
def first_tour(request, tournament_id):
    ...
    matches = []
    for item in items:
       match = Match.objects.get(...)
       matches.append(match)
    return render(request, 'first_tour.html', {'matches':matches})

def edit_match(request, tournament_id, match_id ):
    pass
```

A template where I have a loop for matches and for each:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit_match' match.pk %}">Enter results</a>
```

Why does an error: Reverse for 'edit_match' with arguments '(5L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. appear?

Comment: what is the output of just {{ match.pk }} in the for loop on your template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify all values in the URL:

```
{% url 'edit_match' tournament_id=... pk=match.pk %}
```

You're currently only specifying a value for `pk` which means Django can't find an url called `edit_match` that matches (i.e., that has one unnamed parameter). Your `edit_match` has two named parameters.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It prints: : 
Reverse for 'edit_match' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': 5L, u'tournament': <Tournament: Summer>}' not found.

Comment: @miss_tais your parameter is called `tournament_id`, not `tournament`. They need to match your URL configuration.